# Stroe data in phone whith swift 2 sqlite

Tags: sqlite, swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to store data after the user login is success, i'm using sqlite library but its having errors on the line databasePath, i been looking for tutorials for sqlite on swift but most of them are to old

```
                    if(success == 1)
                    {
                        NSLog("Login SUCCESS");
                        let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
                        let dirPaths =
                        NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,
                            .UserDomainMask, true)

                        let docsDir = dirPaths[0] 

                        databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(
                            "contacts.db")

                        if !filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath as String) {

                            let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

                            if contactDB == nil {
                                println("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
                            }

                            if contactDB.open() {
                                let sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)"
                                if !contactDB.executeStatements(sql_stmt) {
                                    println("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
                                }
                                contactDB.close()
                            } else {
                                println("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: use unresolved identifier 'dataPath'

Comment: `dataPath` looks like it might be missing a `let` in front of it. Unless it's an instance variable, in which case I'm surprised you're initalizing in a method which looks like it isn't a constructor or a view lifecycle callback